# JScrollPane scrolllable list

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I'm trying to set up a scroll bar for which you can always scroll. Here is what I have:

```
public static JScrollPane scrollList(){
    JScrollPane scrollList = new JScrollPane(list);
    scrollableList.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    
    return scrollList;
    
}
```

Problem is that I can only scroll if the list is long and I want to be able to scroll even if empty.

Comment: There's nothing to scroll if the list is empty.

Comment: So what you're basically saying is that you want the scroll bar to be displayed within the JList component even if the list is empty (always displayed)?

Comment: In any case...in your method...where does `scrollableList` come from? Change it to `scrollList`. Or better yet change the JScrollBar variable name to `scrollableList` and return that.